# ordenar arrays de objetos con java

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

estoy haciendo un programa que tiene una lista de string tupo url como se muestra:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
      "Primero1/Segundo1/Tercero2",
      "Primero1/Segundo2/Tercero2",
      "Primero3/Segundo1/Tercero1",
      "Primero1/Segundo2/Tercero3",
      "Primero3/Segundo3/Tercero1",
      "Primero1/Segundo3/Tercero2",
      "Primero3/Segundo2/Tercero3",
      "Primero1/Segundo3/Tercero3",
      "Primero2/Segundo1/Tercero1",
      "Primero2/Segundo1/Tercero2",
      "Primero1/Segundo1/Tercero3",
      "Primero2/Segundo2/Tercero1",
      "Primero1/Segundo3/Tercero1",
      "Primero2/Segundo2/Tercero2",
      "Primero2/Segundo2/Tercero3",
      "Primero2/Segundo3/Tercero1",
      "Primero2/Segundo3/Tercero2",
      "Primero1/Segundo1/Tercero1",
      "Primero2/Segundo1/Tercero3",
      "Primero2/Segundo3/Tercero3",
      "Primero3/Segundo1/Tercero2",
      "Primero3/Segundo1/Tercero3",
      "Primero3/Segundo2/Tercero1",
      "Primero3/Segundo2/Tercero2",
      "Primero1/Segundo2/Tercero1",
      "Primero3/Segundo3/Tercero2",
      "Primero3/Segundo3/Tercero3"
    );
```

Y tengo que ordenarlos e imprimirlos de la siguiente manera:

```
Primero1
    Segundo1
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
    Segundo2
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
    Segundo3
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
Primero2
    Segundo1
      ...
```

hasta el momento pude separarlos de la siguiente manera y ordenar la primer columna con compareTo pero no encuentro como ordenar toda la lista con las tres columnas o los tres parametros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi código:

```
class ListaElementos implements Comparable<ListaElementos>{
  public final String item;
  public final String item2;
  public final String item3;

  public ListaElementos(String item, String item2, String item3) {
    this.item = item;
    this.item2 = item2;
    this.item3 = item3;
  }

  public String getItem() {
    return item;
  }

  public String getItem2() {
    return item2;
  }

  public String getItem3() {
    return item3;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(ListaElementos lista){
    return item.compareTo(lista.getItem());
  }
  
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
      "Primero1/Segundo1/Tercero2",
      "Primero1/Segundo2/Tercero2",
      "Primero3/Segundo1/Tercero1",
      "Primero1/Segundo2/Tercero3",
      "Primero3/Segundo3/Tercero1",
      "Primero1/Segundo3/Tercero2",
      "Primero3/Segundo2/Tercero3",
      "Primero1/Segundo3/Tercero3",
      "Primero2/Segundo1/Tercero1",
      "Primero2/Segundo1/Tercero2",
      "Primero1/Segundo1/Tercero3",
      "Primero2/Segundo2/Tercero1",
      "Primero1/Segundo3/Tercero1",
      "Primero2/Segundo2/Tercero2",
      "Primero2/Segundo2/Tercero3",
      "Primero2/Segundo3/Tercero1",
      "Primero2/Segundo3/Tercero2",
      "Primero1/Segundo1/Tercero1",
      "Primero2/Segundo1/Tercero3",
      "Primero2/Segundo3/Tercero3",
      "Primero3/Segundo1/Tercero2",
      "Primero3/Segundo1/Tercero3",
      "Primero3/Segundo2/Tercero1",
      "Primero3/Segundo2/Tercero2",
      "Primero1/Segundo2/Tercero1",
      "Primero3/Segundo3/Tercero2",
      "Primero3/Segundo3/Tercero3"
    );
  
    List<ListaElementos> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(String item: list){
      
      List<String> textoSeparado = Arrays.asList(item.split("/"));
      //System.out.print(textoSeparado +"\n");
      myList.add(new ListaElementos(textoSeparado.get(0), textoSeparado.get(1),textoSeparado.get(2)));
       
    }

    Collections.sort(myList);
    for(ListaElementos item: myList){
      System.out.print(item.getItem()+" "+item.getItem2()+" "+item.getItem3()+"\n");
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres utilizando `streams` en `java`. La idea es la siguiente:

1. Primero cortar la cadena por el caracter `/`.
2. Agrupar todos los `Primeros` y luego todos los `Segundos` en `TreeMaps`, de manera que las keys queden en orden.
3. Agrupar los `Terceros` en una lista, y finalmente ordenar la lista.
4. Finalmente imprimir la estructura `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`.

El código, que [puedes ejecutar online](https://onlinegdb.com/ITSciROyT) quedaría:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> result = list.stream()
    .map( element -> element.split( "/" ) )
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( strings -> strings[0], TreeMap::new,
              Collectors.groupingBy( strings -> strings[1], TreeMap::new,
              Collectors.mapping( strings -> strings[2],
              Collectors.collectingAndThen( Collectors.toList(),
                 terceros -> terceros.stream().sorted().collect( Collectors.toList())
            )))));

result.entrySet().forEach( primero -> {
    System.out.println( primero.getKey() );
    primero.getValue().forEach( (segundo, terceros) -> {
        System.out.println( "    " + segundo );
        terceros.forEach( tercero -> {
            System.out.println( "       " + tercero );
        });
    });
});
```

Dando como salida:

```
Primero1
    Segundo1
       Tercero1
       Tercero2
       Tercero3
    Segundo2
       Tercero1
       Tercero2
       Tercero3
    Segundo3
       Tercero1
       Tercero2
       Tercero3
Primero2
    Segundo1
       Tercero1
       Tercero2
       Tercero3
    Segundo2
       Tercero1
       Tercero2
       Tercero3
    Segundo3
       Tercero1
       Tercero2
       Tercero3
Primero3
    Segundo1
       Tercero1
       Tercero2
       Tercero3
    Segundo2
       Tercero1
       Tercero2
       Tercero3
    Segundo3
       Tercero1
       Tercero2
       Tercero3
```

---

De manera alternativa puedes crearte tu propia estructura de datos inspirada en un árbol que escale a cualquier cantidad de nodos. Puedes ejecutar el código en [este enlace](https://onlinegdb.com/fxLW2xyFA):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class TreeNode implements Comparable<TreeNode> {
    String name;
    TreeNode parent;
    int level = -1;
    Map<String, TreeNode> children;

    public TreeNode(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = new TreeMap<>();
    }

    public TreeNode addChild(String child) {
        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode( child );
        childNode.level = this.level + 1;

        if (children.containsKey( child )) {
            childNode = this.children.get( child );
        } else {
            this.children.put( child, childNode );
        }

        childNode.setParent( this );
        return childNode;
    }

    public void setParent(TreeNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TreeNode o) {
        return this.name.compareTo( o.name );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + "\n" + children.values().stream()
                .map( treeNode -> " ".repeat( 3 * (treeNode.level) ) + treeNode )
                .collect( Collectors.joining() );
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
                "Primero1/Segundo1/Tercero2/Cuarto1/Quinto1",
                "Primero1/Segundo2/Tercero2/Cuarto2/Quinto2/Sexto1",
                "Primero3/Segundo1/Tercero1",
                "Primero1/Segundo2/Tercero3/Cuarto4/Quinto3/Sexto1/Septimo1",
                "Primero3/Segundo3/Tercero1",
                "Primero1/Segundo3/Tercero2",
                "Primero3/Segundo2/Tercero3",
                "Primero1/Segundo3/Tercero3",
                "Primero2/Segundo1/Tercero1",
                "Primero2/Segundo1/Tercero2",
                "Primero1/Segundo1/Tercero3",
                "Primero2/Segundo2/Tercero1",
                "Primero1/Segundo3/Tercero1",
                "Primero2/Segundo2/Tercero2",
                "Primero2/Segundo2/Tercero3",
                "Primero2/Segundo3/Tercero1",
                "Primero2/Segundo3/Tercero2",
                "Primero1/Segundo1/Tercero1",
                "Primero2/Segundo1/Tercero3",
                "Primero2/Segundo3/Tercero3",
                "Primero3/Segundo1/Tercero2",
                "Primero3/Segundo1/Tercero3/Cuarto5",
                "Primero3/Segundo2/Tercero1",
                "Primero3/Segundo2/Tercero2",
                "Primero1/Segundo2/Tercero1",
                "Primero3/Segundo3/Tercero2",
                "Primero3/Segundo3/Tercero3"
        );


        TreeNode root = new TreeNode( "" );
        for (String s : list) {
            String[] strings = s.split( "/" );
            TreeNode child = root;
            for (String st : strings) {
                child = child.addChild( st );
            }
        }

        System.out.println( root );
    }
}
```

La salida sería:

```
Primero1
   Segundo1
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
         Cuarto1
            Quinto1
      Tercero3
   Segundo2
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
         Cuarto2
            Quinto2
               Sexto1
      Tercero3
         Cuarto4
            Quinto3
               Sexto1
                  Septimo1
   Segundo3
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
Primero2
   Segundo1
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
   Segundo2
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
   Segundo3
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
Primero3
   Segundo1
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
         Cuarto5
   Segundo2
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
   Segundo3
      Tercero1
      Tercero2
      Tercero3
```

Comment: Tienes razon muchas gracias por la ayuda.